# Get feature from WFS based on the location from points

Tags: qgis, wfs, spatial-join

I have several hundred GPS points which I want to join additional data to (e.g. corresponding district). Since the points are spread over a whole country it seems not possible to pre-load every district data from the WFS server since it would mean to fetch several hundred thousand datasets and only use a few of them.

The question is: How to fetch (and connect) only the data where a point is within?

Comment: most WFS support things like intersects, within bounding box, etc.  You would add it as part of the url.  You'll have to find docs for the service and see what is available and how to use it.

Comment: But i guess it would be some custom pyhton code, right?

Comment: Yes.  I'm not aware of any tools in qgis that will do that for you.